# "evaluateJavascript()" returns "null" as localStorage value of webView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, local-storage, android-webview

(Sorry for my poor English)

I have a web page which set a local storage value like `localStorage.setItem('name', 'myName')` , I load this web page inside a webView and I want to access to this local storage value inside the android app so I used below code but it returns "null", it takes half a day but i can't fix it, I'm not android developer so explain me a little more please.

```
package com.example.myWebViewApp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.ValueCallback
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)

        val webSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webSettings.allowFileAccess = true
        webSettings.allowContentAccess = true
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webSettings.textZoom = 100
        webSettings.allowFileAccess = true

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.99:3333")

        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {

                myWebView.evaluateJavascript(
                    "window.localStorage.getItem('name');",
                    ValueCallback<String?> {
                            n -> run { Log.d("nameTag", "$n") }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        val refreshLayout = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.swipeRefresher)

        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            refreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
                refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                myWebView.reload()
            }, 2000)
        }
    }
}
```